# Angular 8: object passing through service, data is not changing

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to pass some data from one component to other, not related, component. Seems like easy thing to do through service. Unfortunetely it's not working and I don't know why. Here's my service:

*data.service.ts*

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: "root"
})
export class DataService {
   private searchData = new BehaviorSubject<CityData>(null);

   currentSearchData = this.searchData.asObservable();

   changeSearchData(data: CityData) {
     this.searchData.next(data);
   }
}
```

*header.component.ts*

```
onCityClick(city: CityData) {
   this._data.changeSearchData(city);
}
```

After calling this method seems like nothing changed, especially this subject... Its value stays null (or some default value that I've tried) when I'm subscribing to it. Inside method it takes proper value.

*home.component.ts*

```
ngOnInit() {
   this._data.currentSearchData.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
 }
```

As I said, it is only "null" being printed. I even tested subscribing on click - the same result. 
Worth to mention, header is declared in app module, when home is in content.module. Also, what can be important, I had a problem with NullInjection error in Header with DataService and I needed to add option "providedIn". Now there is no error but it's not working. At the same time ApiService while being right next to it, works perfectly fine without it and just being declared as provider in app.module. I think these providers/modules might be problematic but I don't know how to solve it.

*app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent, HeaderComponent],
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     HttpClientModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     ContentModule
   ],
   providers: [ApiService, /*DataService being here not helps*/],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule {}
```

**Edit**
Tried with another approach to service and outcome is exactly the same.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class DataService {
  constructor() {}

private _searchData = new BehaviorSubject<CityData>(
    new CityData(null, null, null, null)
 );

 get searchData$(): Observable<CityData> {
   return this._searchData.asObservable();
 }

 set searchData(data: CityData) {
   this._searchData.next(data);
 }
}
```

Comment: Your question as written does not provide enough information to help you out, but  the most common scenario where this would happen is for your two components to be using different instances of the service.

Comment: @NicholasK currentSearchData is an observable, it will not have a .next method. The code exposed here looks ok-ish.

Comment: True. I feel the `currentSearchData` is not getting updated with the most recent values as it is evaluated just once outside the method.

Comment: `currentSearchData` is using value of `searchData` (which should be updated) and makes it observable, isn't it? If not, how to fix it? @Nicholas K, ok, so I guess I should make some kind of getter to avoid using `currentSearchData` right?

Comment: This looks ok to me. You need to make sure that both your components use same instance of the DataService. The `providedIn: "root"` is used to make the service available at root level, in that case you do not need to your service to  `providers:[..]` list in app.module.ts

Comment: That's what I'm thinking but not sure.. Can you create a stackblitz to replicate the issue?

Comment: Stackblitz connecting with git repo to infinity... Still confusing thing for me is that I cannot declare this DataService in app.module in providers list, despite that I'm doing it with ApiService. Seems like header has different instance of DataService somehow.

Comment: Verify CityData receiving or not by adding console.log in   changeSearchData(data: CityData)

Comment: @Shakeer Hussain, I did and received data is fine.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it by renaming file from data.service.ts to DataService.ts (and all imports respectively). Also declaring service in app.module in the providers list. Fun fact, ApiService from api.srevice.ts is still injecting perfectly... :D